# Leibniz convergence test to compute the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, irrational-numbers

Can we compute the limit of a series using Leibniz test?

This is the problem I am struggling with:

" Let $(a_{n})_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of natural numbers, $a_{n} \ge 2$ ,

Let $b_{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{a_{1}} + \frac{1}{a_{1}a_{2}} +- \dots + (-1)^n\frac{1}{a_1a_2...a_n}$      , $n = 1,2,3, \dots$

Prove that:

a) $(b_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is convergent

b) if $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is unbounded, then the limit of $(b_n)_{n \ge 1} \in \mathbb{R\setminus Q}$ "

(Source: Romanian National Olympiad Shortlist)

It's easy to prove point a) using Leibniz test. I may be wrong, but I belive the test can be used in point b), to prove the irrationality. Is there any way to compute the limit?

Comment: Since you don't know what the $a_n$ are, other than being unbounded, how do you expect to compute a limit? Try showing for all $N$, that $\lim_n Nb_n$ cannot be integer.

Comment: I couldn't solve it using this idea.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational. I will read with care your proof this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Suppose that $b_n \rightarrow \frac{p}{q}$ , where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z^*}$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ , we have $|b_n - \frac{p}{q}| < \epsilon$ , and by choosing $\epsilon := \frac{\epsilon}{|q|}$ , we get:

$|1 - \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_1a_2} + \dots (-1)^n\frac{1}{a_1a_2...a_n} - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{\epsilon}{|q|}$

Multiplying both sides with $|q|a_1a_2...a_n$ , we get:

$|q(a_1a_2...a_n - a_1a_2...a_{n-1} + \dots (-1)^n) - p| < \epsilon$

By setting $d_n = a_1a_2...a_n - a_1a_2...a_{n-1} + \dots (-1)^n$, we get that $d_n \rightarrow \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$

Since $a_n \ge 2$ for any $n \ge 1$ we get that $a_1a_2...a_n \ge 2^n$ , which implies $a_1a_2...a_n \rightarrow \infty$

Because $d_n = a_1a_2...a_{n-1}(a_n - 1) + a_1a_2...a_{n-3}(a_{n-2}-1) + \dots$ and $a_n - 1 \ge 1$ ,

we get that $d_n \rightarrow \infty$, contradiction

Can anybody tell me if this is correct?

Comment: You can't take $\epsilon = \epsilon/q$.

Comment: Why not? Since the inequality holds for any epsion > 0 , and q is fixed?

Comment: You are taking *simultaneously* two values for $\epsilon$ (except if $q = 1$).

Comment: I am taking only one value. The definition of the limit states that |a_n - L| < epsilon for any epsilon > 0 (where L is the limit of a_n). For any epsilon there is a number M>0 where M = epsilon / |q|. But M can be any positive number since epsilon is a positive number chosen randomly. This means that |a_n -  L| < M where M can be any positive, which leads to the conclusion that L is the limit of a_n,

Comment: But my post is wrong since I forgot to muliply in the module p * a1a2..an. I found the error. But still in search of the solution....

Comment: You did assign two values to $\epsilon$. The phrase $\epsilon := \frac{\epsilon}{|q|}$ is simply a mathematical impossibility. This is math, not a computer program. However, that is a small point, since really what you are doing is choosing $n$ large enough that $|b_n - p/q| < \epsilon/|q|$, which is fine. You just didn't phrase it well. But in addition to not multiplying $p$, you also didn't multiply $\epsilon$ by $a_1...a_n$, which is the big error.